# Authenticating a Request with FormUrlEncoded Body

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a scenario where I want to verify that every request has a valid header attribute. This attribute is a digital signature which essentially is a hash of the request url and the request body, in this case a form-url-encoded body.

So I did the typical thing and created an action filter as follows:

```
class SomeActionFilter @Inject()(val executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends ActionFilter[Request] {

  override protected def filter[A](request: Request[A]): Future[Option[Result]] = Future.successful {
    // here I want to get the request body which I know is a form url encoded request body
    val body = request.body //problem here is that body is of type A

  }

}
```

What I really want is to get request.body to be of type Option[Map[String, Seq[String]]] which is what a form url encoded body is. I could do this, ie swap the type parameter A with AnyContent like this and then I can get at a request.body.asFormUrlEncoded

```
class SomeActionFilter @Inject()(val executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends ActionFilter[Request] {

  override protected def filter[AnyContent](request: Request[AnyContent]): Future[Option[Result]] = Future.successful {
encoded request body
    val body = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded

  }

}
```

Is that the right thing to do here, to swap the type parameter like this? Or do I check if the body is of type Option[Map[String, Seq[String]]] using asInstanceOf and reject the request if it isn't? I'm a bit lost on how to approach this.

Comment: The point of the type parameterization on the Request is so that it can be generalised for any content type. As such, you could potentially write a filter method which works on a general request value. In your case, you want to write logic of a specific content type - form url encoded - and so it is perfectly ok to specifiy precisely the parameterization on the Request type and then write your logic accordingly which is specific to form-url-encoded requests.